# JavaScript inputEl.checked Inside of Label

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I have an checkbox inside of the corresponding label for it.

```
<div class="list-group-item preference">
   <label for="alertnotices">
      <div class="preference-title">Notices</div>
      <div class="preference-body"></div>
      <input id="alertnotices" class="preference-toggle" name="preference" type="checkbox" data-preference="self.enable.alertnotices">
      <span class="preference-toggle-display"></span>
   </label>
</div>
```

I have an even listener on the label for when it's clicked to check the state of the checkbox

```
$.each(document.querySelectorAll('.preference label'), function(idx, toggle) {
    toggle.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(toggle.querySelector('input[name="preference"]').checked);
    });
});
```

When the label is clicked the previous state and the new state are both logged.
I created an example on jsFiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/wuFxt/ I just need the new checkbox state.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your fiddle .. please explain more what your problem is

Comment: Do you want to show only current state?  http://jsfiddle.net/wuFxt/1/

Comment: If you click inside of the label (border area) in general and not the checkbox you get two checked values, the value of the checkbox before the click and the value after the click.

Comment: So above example fixed this problem.

Comment: Not so much. For printing it onto the screen, yes, but for something like AJAX no (updating the state immediately when it's changed instead of say save button), because it still emits two values.

Comment: You should start with valid HTML - you can't have a DIV inside a label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`check http://jsfiddle.net/WXMHS/`

**one solution**:

just bind to **.preference-toggle** instaed of **label**.

**why the question example will emit twice?** (ps. just my experience, I can't guarantee the reason is right exactly.)

**1st emit:** clicking the **label for="id"** tag (except target button itself) will trigger a **click** event for target button.

**2th emit:** the label trigger button click event, and then, **bubble** to the label tag. so that the 2th our label-click-handler has been executed twice.

I wish it could help you.